# Change Opencart 2 success page

Tags: opencart

Where can I change the URL for my OpenCart 2 success page?
The way that my site is set up, open cart is a module of the larger site. 
On completion of an order I need the user to be returned to a page within the main site rather than the opencart.

Alternately, changing the URL for the "Continue" button would work, but from an analytics perspective , that would be inferior.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Catalog/view/theme/yourtheme/common/header.tpl

And add this code to it

```
$current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
if (strpos($current_url,"checkout/success")) {
    header("Location: Yourdomain");
}
```

And you change the "Yourdomain" to the page that you want it to be redirected to just copy and paste your domain.

If you are using some custom URL's that a module generates them than you need to change the `"checkout/success"` to what ever URL your success page is at.

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to controller/checkout/success.php

`$this->response->redirect('http://www.yoursite.com');`

Just make sure that redirect code is added after cart and session clearing. In my version you, can add it to line 47.